# Copy all files but ignored in .gitignore

Tags: javascript, build, gruntjs, build-automation

I want to copy all files to another dir (with grunt-contrib-copy) except files that are listed in .gitignore.
This is my current setup:
.gitignore:

```
/vendor
/node_modules
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "grunt-cpy",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "Gruntfile.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "gitignore-globs": "^0.1.1",
    "grunt": "^0.4.5",
    "grunt-cli": "~0.1.11",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "^0.7.0",
    "grunt-contrib-clean": "^0.6.0"
  }
}
```

Gruntfile.js

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {

    var parse = require('gitignore-globs');
    var globs = parse('.gitignore', { negate: true } );
    grunt.log.ok( globs );

    // Project configuration.
    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg     : grunt.file.readJSON( 'package.json' ),
        clean: {
            pre_build: [
                'build/'
            ]
        },
        copy: {
            build: {
                options : {
                    mode :true
                },
                src: [
                    '**',
                    globs
                ],
                dest: 'build/'
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks( 'grunt-contrib-clean' );
    grunt.loadNpmTasks( 'grunt-contrib-copy' );

    grunt.registerTask( 'default', [ 'clean:pre_build', 'copy'] );
};
```

Debug output of globs:

```
!/vendor,!/vendor/**,!/node_modules,!/node_modules/**
```

But it doesn't work this way. It just copies everything. I also tried the package 'gitignore-to-glob' and 'grunt-copy-to'. Can somebody help to archive this?
I'm on Windows.

Comment: How does `globs` output in the _console_?

Comment: @No3x I ran the above grunt configuration , it worked for me. The debug output came out to be ``!**/node_modules,!**/node_modules/**`` . In case you want to check the code see https://github.com/pra85/grunt-copy-gitignore-blob

Comment: @Prayag Verma thanks for your effort! I created a dontcopy.txt, added /dontcopy.txt to .gitignore ran grunt and the dontcopy.txt was copied to build. So it's the same behaviour. (It actually works when adding without / prefix but this is dangerous ) My current workaround is to execute `git checkout-index -a -f --prefix=build/` which is not the same but fits my needs as workaround so far. But I would be happy to use a copy grunt module anyway.